# get rid of apostrophe in mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql

can someone please help, i have a text area form that users can type in content to and submit it and then the content gets stored in mysql table.

The problem i am having is that whenever a user types an apostrophe ' this is inserted with a / and i want to get rid of the /.

my column is utf8_general_ci format (long text) am i even using the right type of format here?

also here's my code maybe i need to put something in the mysql?

please can someone show me where im going wrong thank you.

html form:

```
<form action="includes/changebio.php" method="post" id="form1">         
 <textarea id="bio" style="width: 448px; 
    margin-top:3px;
    text-align:left;
    margin-left:-2px;
    height: 120px;
    resize: none; 
    border: hidden;" textarea name="bio" data-id="bio" maxlength="710"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($profile['bio']); ?></textarea>
<input type="image" src="assets/img/icons/save-edit.png"class="bio-submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit"/>
</form>
```

mysql:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<?php
require_once("session.php"); 
require_once("functions.php");
require('_config/connection.php');
?>
<?php 
session_start();
include '_config/connection.php'; 
$bio = $_POST['bio'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT bio FROM ptb_profiles WHERE id=".$_SESSION['user_id']."");
if(!$result) 
{ 
echo "The username you entered does not exist"; 
} 
else 
if($bio!= mysql_result($result, 0)) 
{ 
echo ""; 
    $sql=mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_profiles SET bio ='".mysql_real_escape_string($bio)."' WHERE id=".$_SESSION['user_id'].""); 
}
header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
?>
<?php ob_end_flush() ?>
```

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possible cases

1. You have magic quotes on. [Turn them off.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php)
2. Some sort of **Sanitize Them All** function run on all your input data. Get rid of it.

Comment: @JohnJames — You read page at the other end of the link in the answer.